# Pulling part of changes from master to another branch

Tags: git

The problem is that I have two branches:

1. master
2. feature-branch

On feature-branch I have a very simplified version of the repository, which serves me as a landing page. As the master branch is much further in development process from the feature-branch I would like to pull some of its changes.

What I would like to do is to pull changes in folder `a`,`b` and `c`. I've tried cherry pick but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Git doesn't support what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't support this work flow. `feature-branch` should contain everything from `master` because eventually it will be merged into `master` to integrate whatever feature you are working on.